# css - how do I make svgs responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, responsive-design

I am getting `svg` data by api call and appending it to `div` in a DOM. There are 13-14 svg elements I am getting and appending it to a single `div`. I want to display all this svgs in a row. If I give `width: 5.5%;` to svg elements, all the svgs display in a row. But when I resize window or monitor size is small, all svgs overlap each other. I've created an example in jsfiddle. [Please find this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o71v0dz/13/)

I tried with `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` in svg but it's not working.

Update: I've updated fiddle. In a default size of resule in jsfiddle, overlapping is visible. I want it to be responsive.

**How do I make these svgs responsive so that it doesn't overlap each other?**

Comment: I'm unclear as to what is overlapping what in your fiddle.

Comment: You might want to consider: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/ ♦ http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/05/rethinking-responsive-svg/

Comment: tried both the solutions but not working.

Answer (score 0):

For these purpose better to use img tag:

```
<img src="path_to_svg" style="width: 5.5%" />
```

And in the svg file you should add attribute such as

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%"> .... </svg>
```

In this case image will resize as you want.

Comment: giving `src` is not possible as svgs are returned in api call and I am appending it to `div`.